# C# вызвать переменную из другого метода

Tags: c#, методы

подскажите пожалуйста, мне нужно вызвать public class CallSKP из другого метода, чтоб использовать там значение переменной "text". как это сделать?

имеется вот такой код:

```
public class GR21 : SKP
        {
            public GR21(string name) : base(name) { }
        }

        public class CallSKP
        {
            public static void Main(WorkbookItem workbookItem)
            {
                var curBook = workbookItem;
                Info(new GR21(Common.ExtractText(curBook, "RAZ1S" + GR2 + "GRC")));
            }

            public static void Info(SKP namecode)
            {
                string text = namecode.Code;
                //Console.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }
```

так как тот метод я править не могу, и не могу там использовать WorkbookItem.

Comment: Статические методы вызываются без создания экземпляров. Вот так: CallSKP.Info(namecode);

Comment: в Info(SKP namecode) вам нужно возращать text  вот так: return text;

Comment: Спасибо Cooller Floyd, но мне почему то пишет что Info(SKP namecode) не существует в данном контексте

Comment: Ануар, вы не могли бы пояснить поточнее - я указал public static void Info(SKP namecode)
            {
                string text = namecode.Code;
                return text;
            } но он пишет что return возвращает значение void.

Comment: если можно сделать проще подскажите пожалуйста, мне вообще нужно вот это public static void Main(WorkbookItem workbookItem)
            {
                var curBook = workbookItem;
                GR1 = Common.ExtractText(curBook, "RAZ1S" + GR2 + "GRC");
            } и обратиться чтоб забрать значение GR1.